# XPath context is not available in linked flow

Tags: xml, xpath, mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I have two flows
1. main-flow.xml
2. linked-flow.xml

The linked flow will be called by using VM queue.
When I try to use the Xpath expression at the main flow, it is working fine.
However, at the linked flow, the Xpath is not available.

Tried after adding the Mule namespace definition in both flows, still not working.

I have to verify, an XML node, whether it is present or not.

```
<root>
  <child1>value1</child1>
  <child2>
    <child3>
      <child4>value4</child4>
    </child3>
  </child2>
</root>
```

Need to check, if the node node3 is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

To test whether a node exists or not, you can use boolean logic :

```
boolean(/root/child2/child3)
```

or if a mule namespace exists :

```
boolean(/mule:root/mule:child2/mule:child3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case this is not working as expected.  If the Xml has namespace,  it will not work. Any more suggestions.

Comment: No problem to do `boolean(/ns:root/ns:child2/ns:child3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check an existence of node in your XPATH by using [count()](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example7.html) function.
[How to check via XPATH if element exist in all parent's elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853882/how-to-check-via-xpath-if-element-exist-in-all-parents-elements)
Count will return 0 if node doesn't exists